# The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl, taglib

i need some help, i wanted to do a program and used

```
if(session.getAttribute("logged")!="1"){ 
 String err="You must be logged in!!"; 
 request.setAttribute( "error", err ); 
 String nextJSP = "/login.jsp"; 
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP); 
dispatcher.forward(request,response); }
```

%>

In a jsp, but my boss told me to use jstl So i changed it to:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <c:if test="${session.getAttribute('logged')!=null}"> 
      <jsp:forward page="login.jsp">
      </jsp:forward>
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="${session.getAttribute('logged')==null}">
      <jsp:forward page="princ.jsp"> </jsp:forward>
 </c:if>
```

And i get a nasty error:

```
 "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application "
```

I searched the internet for some fixes, i've put the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-javadoc.jar in my library, even put javaee.jar in the Tomcat library, but still got no solution to this, can somebody help me please?
PS: i got Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.(INDIGO) Tomcat 7.08

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your taglib URI is wrong.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

This URI is from the old and EOL'ed JSTL 1.0 library. Since JSTL 1.1, you need an extra `/jsp` in the path because the taglib's internal workings were changed because the EL part was moved from JSTL to JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Further, the JAR files which you attempted to drop in `/WEB-INF/lib` are wrong. The `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-javadoc.jar` is contains only the JSTL javadocs and the `javaee.jar` contains the entire Java EE API which may be desastreus because Tomcat ships with parts of it already (JSP/Servlet) which may [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706).

Remove them all. You need the [jstl-1.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) file.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: still the same error with the taglib changed, I'm gonna check the wiki page for some info, maybe i'll sort it out somehow, thanks :D

Comment: Thank you for the link to the jstl-1.2.jar file. I have now tried with several files saying they were 1.2, but they didn't work. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

I think you should include [jstl-1.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar).

Comment: not helping :(, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Also, instead of

```
<c:if test="${session.getAttribute('logged')!=null}">
```

use one of the following

```
<c:if test="${sessionScoped.logged != null}">  
<c:if test="${sessionScoped[logged] != null}">
<c:if test="${logged != null}">
```