# Generating liferay-ui elements in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I need to generate several `<liferay-ui:panel>`s. The idea would be to have a JSP that looks something like this:

```
<liferay-ui:panel-container extended="true">
    <%=MyJavaClass.generatePanel() %>
</liferay-ui:panel-container>
```

and Java code along the lines of:

```
class MyJavaClass {
    public static String generatePanel() {
        String result="<liferay-ui:panel collapsible=\"false\" extended=\"true\" title=\"Some Title\">Some Content</liferay-ui:panel>";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Liferay won't convert the `<liferay-ui panel...>`. I'm guessing this is because it only does so *before* the java code is executed, so I'm not getting any panels.

Is there any way to get Liferay to go through the JSP *after* I generated the panels? Or am I missing a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the line `<liferay-ui:panel collapsible=\"false\" extended=\"true\" title=\"Some Title\">Some Content</liferay-ui:panel>"` to a jsp tag located at `WEB-INF/tags/liferay-panel.tag`.

And include the tag in the required jsp.

Below is the solution for the same:

**liferay-panel.tag**

```
<liferay-ui:panel collapsible=\"false\" extended=\"true\" title=\"Some Title\">
    Some Content
</liferay-ui:panel>
```

**And include the tag like this:**

```
<%@taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"% >
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<liferay-ui:panel-container extended="true">
     <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="20" step="1">
        <tags:liferay-panel/>
     </c:forEach>
</liferay-ui:panel-container>
```

Comment: How would I use that fragment? With `<liferay-util:include...`? Would my variables from the parent JSP still be in scope?

Comment: I have given the code, please check and let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I think my code example was poorly chosen. The problem is that I don't know how many panels I'm going to need at compile time (and that the content of each panel must be generated as well).

Comment: Edited my answer can you check now.

Comment: I tried, but can not get `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>` to work. I googled and found some changes in recent Liferay versions. How would I go about including that TLD in Liferay 6.1?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976281/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either-web/9976952#9976952. Add the jstl jar in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Your example works. Can I somehow access my variables in that tag file?

Comment: Figured it out. Using `<%@ attribute name="myVariable" required="true" type="javax.servlet.ServletContext" %>` in the tag works just fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can access variables in pagecontext, session, request. On top of that if you want to something else, you should use tag attributes. A Tag file can take attributes.