# Unable to find JSTL directory

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm new with JSP and i got the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

calling this taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

After some searches, i known that it is a JSP tag-library problem and then, with **tomcat 7**, i ought to put the library *jstl-1.2.jar*, which i've downloaded, into the folder *WEB-INF/lib* checking that all permissions was right.
Well, i've just done it refreshing tomcat7 but nothing is happened.

This is the directory path, created by NetBeans together with the project:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/jsp_test/web/WEB-INF/lib
```

(the last path "lib" is created by me).

Where is my error?
Could anyone explain better how the things work please?

Comment: What is *jstl-1.2.jsp* ? It should be *jstl-1.2.jar* ![This](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) jar .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9977825/112500

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701326/112500

http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/web/jstl-impl/1.2/

Comment: Yeah jar, i'm sorry :)

Comment: moreover sometimes when i refresh the page i got another error instead the above one:
`HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp`
I'm a little bit' confused :(

Comment: remove servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar from web-inf/lib folder if exists... restart the server...

Comment: in my WEB-INF/lib i have just the _jstl-1.2.jar_ and nothing else. Moreover i've seen in similar issues, that i have to remove the _standard.jar_.
Where is it?

Comment: Must i set up something in my _beans.xml_, downstairs the lib folder?