# i don't understand where i am doing the mistake. i am using eclipse neon IDE for this code

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<c:out value="${'Welcome to SevenMentor'}"/>
```

Output:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
```

Type Exception Report

```
Message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:293)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:80)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:492)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1448)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:145)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:201)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/8.5.14

Comment: Is it a maven project?

Comment: Add following deoendency in pom.xml https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976281/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either-web)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r)

Answer (score 0):

Your error basically says that necessary jar files are missing.

1. > If it's a maven project then please add the dependencies.
2. > If it's a normal project. please download and add the jar files in the eclipse 
   >   web directory.

Seeing the error, i guess you need jsp libraries and jstl libraries.

Comment: It's normal project and i have downloaded jstl-1.2.jar and included in my project. But still i am facing this problem. and are you talking about jsp jar file? or JSP tag jar file?

Comment: Can you show the jar files you have included? I guess there are either multiple versions of jstl or `standard.jar`